# On Blur event on telerik dropdownlist

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, blur, focusout

I am using telerik dropdownlist in telerik grid. Now i want to fire some validation on   dropdownlist on blur or focus out if value is "select". Here i am not changing items in dropdownlist. Initially it is "Select" only. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$('#Claim_Status').live('blur', function () {                    

        if ($('#Claim_Status').val() == "") {

            var str = "<span class='field-validation-error' data-valmsg-replace='true' data-valmsg-for='Claim_Status'>";
            str = str + "<span class='' for='Claim_Status' generated='true'>Field is required.</span></span>";
            $("span[data-valmsg-for='Claim_Status']").replaceWith(str);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the [change](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-combobox-client-api-and-events.html#OnChange) event of the DropDownList and execute your logic when it occurs?

Comment: OnChange event gets triggered only when i change selected item in dropdownlist not when i lose focus or on blur.